# setup.py: expected parenthesized list when required package name contains a dash

Tags: django, setuptools, distribute

I am writing a reusable Django app as described here:
https://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.5.x/intro/reusable-apps.html

When I specify a requirement in setup.py that contains a dash in the package name, setup.py will not run.  For example, if my setup.py contains this line:

```
requires=[ 'djangotinymce', 'MtFileUtil', 'Django', 'PyYAML', ],
```

Then it works properly.

```
python ./setup.py sdist
running sdist
...
Creating tar archive
```

If I change the line to look like this:

```
requires=[ 'django-tinymce', 'MtFileUtil', 'Django', 'PyYAML', ],
```

We get a strange error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 32, in <module>
    'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/home/travis/venv/deleteme/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 259, in __init__
    getattr(self.metadata, "set_" + key)(val)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 1220, in set_requires
    distutils.versionpredicate.VersionPredicate(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/versionpredicate.py", line 113, in __init__
    raise ValueError("expected parenthesized list: %r" % paren)
ValueError: expected parenthesized list: '-tinymce'
```

I'm unsure what to make of this.  I want to require django-tinymce but I can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `require` argument is from `distutils` and expects python package names (some [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages) here). Since you're using `setuptools`, you should use the `install_requires` argument instead, which does support PyPI package names:

```
install_requires=['djangotinymce', 'MtFileUtil', 'Django', 'PyYAML'],
```

More info on [Specifying Dependencies](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html) in the Python Packaging User Guide.

Comment: Just to add clarification to the above comment, you need to remove the -'s. To python these are arithmetical operators. Ie 'django-tinymce' -> 'djangotinymce'.

Comment: They can be underscores instead of hyphens.